# Only refresh a web page on weekday and between 9-5

Tags: javascript, web

I am stuck on a bit of a problem and I wondered if you knowledgeable people might be able to help. I have a number of screens up on walls showing various stats that refresh every 10 minutes of so using some basic javascript. They run reports which naturally add some load to our DB and reporting servers so I have been asked to only refresh the pages on weekdays - and to only refresh the pages between 9-5 on these weekdays

I am having a hard time finding examples that do both of these things together - can anyone help me at all?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using `crontab` for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks - I cant actually as I am calling a report from the front end - it isn't a job in the background but I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sophisticated but should work:

```
var d = new Date(); // now

// now is between 9-to-5 on a weekday?
if ((1 <= d.getDay()) 
      && (d.getDay() <= 5) 
      && (9 <= d.getHours()) 
      && (d.getHours() < 17)) { 
    reload();
}
```